# C++ PEB_LDR_DATA access module lists

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I am trying to access and print the 3 module lists in PEB_LDR_DATA(InLoadOrderModuleList, InMemoryOrderModuleList, InInitializationOrderModuleList).

I have been able to access InMemoryOrderModuleList list and print it, but when I am trying to access the InLoadOrderModuleList / InInitializationOrderModuleList I get a error that is not recognized.

I am new to c++ and window API and after I have done some reading about the structure of PEB_LDR_DATA in few websites I saw different structures.

for example : [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb_ldr_data), [sandsprite](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_the_Peb_Loader_Data_List.html), [nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/PEB_LDR_DATA.html)

Which one is right? Why I have not been able to access them or how to access then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your nirsoft link has the most complete definition. Microsoft's documentation will only provide certain "public" fields, so that it can change the definition at a later date.

The [Terminus Project](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_PEB_LDR_DATA_combined.html) provides good definitions (based off of headers and symbol data), showing how the structures have changed between OS versions.

Current Win10 (x64) era version:

```
0x0000  unsigned long Length
0x0004  uint8_t Initialized
0x0008  void * SsHandle
0x0010  struct _LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList
0x0020  struct _LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList
0x0030  struct _LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList
0x0040  void * EntryInProgress
0x0048  uint8_t ShutdownInProgress
0x0050  void * ShutdownThreadId
```

Comment: I am trying to access the other lists like this ```(PLIST_ENTRY)(pebLdrData + 0x0010);```  with no success. how should I access it?

Comment: ```pebLdrData ``` is a ```PPEB_LDR_DATA```

Comment: Ask that in a new question.

Comment: I post new question, but how to access it is part of the post.